# How get the parent directory in command Line (Batch)

Tags: batch-file

The Folder struct is

c:\yyyy\ 4 \ _build \file.cmd

I tried in the file.cmd file of excute this script

```
SET Source=c:\CompilationStaging\{THIS}\%FolderName%
```

in the {THIS} part I need the parent of the parent directories in this case would be 4

thanks

Comment: No, I need in this path c:\yyyy\ 4 \ _build \file.cmd get the number 4 from a file.CMD file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a `for` loop, the `%~nI` substitution extracts the file or directory name of the variable `I`.  With that in mind, and knowing that the parent of the parent directory is `..\..`:

```
for %%a in ("..\..") do ( set "target=%%~na" )
```

However, in the example you gave, "4" is the parent directory.  Not the parent of the parent.  So in your case, you'd use `..` instead of `..\..`:

```
C:\yyyy\4\_build>type paths.cmd
@echo off
for %%a in ("..") do ( set "target=%%~na" )
echo %target%
C:\yyyy\4\_build>paths
4
```

Comment: This show me yyyyy, but I modified for that
`for %%a in ("..") do ( set target=%%~na )`
and work :) thanks man

Comment: FYI, `_build` is your current directory.  `4` is the parent.  `yyyy` is the parent of the parent.  Glad it worked for you.

Comment: I have other problem with that... the result is : '4 ' with a blank space at the finish of the string and I need only '4' some Idea?

Comment: @David:  Yes, sorry, that's because I didn't quote the "set" statement.  Fix it with `set "target=%%~na"`.  I edited the post to fix it, too.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (`!parentNameOfParent!` is the desired value) :

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set fileP="c:\yyyy\4\_build\file.cmd"
for %%a in (%fileP%) do (
    set parent=%%~dpa
    cd !parent!\..
    set PPPath=!cd!
    for %%x in ("!PPPath!") do (
        set parentNameOfParent=%%~nx
    )
)

echo !parentNameOfParent!
```

Comment: Great, but this show me: _build and I need the previous directory: 4

Comment: Strange... It shows "b b" from "C:\a\b b\c\file.ext". So this is parent of parent folder.

Comment: I even changed file path to be exactly like in initial example. It shows "4".